# How can I make a div appear when hovering over a SVG path?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm working on this SVG image , [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7t7km1y/4/)

```
 <div id='one'>
  items that should appear when hovering over 01(red circle) on the svg image
</div>

<div id='two'>
  items that should appear when hovering over 02(green circle) on the svg image
</div>
<div id='three'>
  items that should appear when hovering over 03(purple circle) on the svg image
</div>
```

I need the div appear when hovering over the relevant SVG circle , and the circle should be highlighted when hovering over it,

I'm new to JS and don't know where to start , I looked for libraries like SVG.js and vivus.js but they are too complicated for this small task , please help me out , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, show/hide a div when the mouse enters and leaves the desired circle respectively.

Below is the snippet for div toggle and see the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y550gju8/)

JS

```
$(function() {
  $("#XMLID_359_").hover(function(){
    $('#one').toggle();
    $(this).addClass('transform');
  });

  $("#XMLID_362_").hover(function(){
    $('#two').toggle();
    $(this).addClass('transform');
  });

  $("#XMLID_67_").hover(function(){
    $('#three').toggle();
    $(this).addClass('transform');
  });

  $("#XMLID_359_,#XMLID_362_, #XMLID_67_").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('transform');
  });
});
```

CSS

```
#one, #two, #three{
  display: none;
}
#XMLID_359_, #XMLID_362_, #XMLID_67_{
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
.transform{
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
#XMLID_362_.transform{
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translateX(-72.3px);
}
```

You would have to include the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library in the application.

Comment: amazing ! Thank you so much , can I know how to highlight the relevant circle when hovering over as well ?

Comment: What do you mean by highlight? Should it fill with some color or get in focus or its just zooms out?

Comment: color of the circle get lighter or get in focus maybe ?

Comment: See the update to the answer, i didnt have much time so i added a `transform` and `transition` css rules to the red circle. You could do something similar as per your requirement.

Comment: @vicbyte, please feel free to edit my answer, I will approve it if its a better way.

Comment: I had to improve the edit with the transformation css, so that @user8006503 can better understand.Thanks.

Comment: @Sajal updated the code once more, cause i noticed a bug with the middle circle :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```js
function showMe1(){
document.getElementById('one').style.color="";
}

function showMe2(){
document.getElementById('two').style.color="";
}


function showMe3(){
document.getElementById('three').style.color="";
}

document.getElementById('one').style.color="transparent";
document.getElementById('two').style.color="transparent";
document.getElementById('three').style.color="transparent";
```

```css
 div:hover {
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

```html
     <div id='one' onmouseover="showMe1()">
      items that should appear when hovering over 01(red circle) on the svg image
    </div>

    <div id='two' onmouseover="showMe2()">
      items that should appear when hovering over 02(green circle) on the svg image
    </div>
    <div id='three' onmouseover="showMe3()">
      items that should appear when hovering over 03(purple circle) on the svg image
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks , but I wanted to know who it can be worked with the SVG